# connection_config deprecated warning with RSpec after migrating to Rails 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-activerecord, rspec-rails, money-rails

I upgraded an app to Rails 6.1.0 (from 6.0.3.3, by creating a new api-only app, adding RSpec, then copying needed files over manually).

I am seeing the following warning when I run RSpec:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: connection_config is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 6.2 (Use 
connection_db_config instead) (called from <top (required)> at 
[...app/models/application_record.rb:1].
```

I did not change the `ApplicationRecord` class from the default:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

I only see this warning when I run RSpec. I have not seen it in the rails console or in the Rails server log.

Here is my `config/database.yml`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: <%= ENV.fetch('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost') %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch('POSTGRES_USER', 'postgres') %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch('POSTGRES_PASSWORD', '') %>
  database: <%= ENV.fetch('POSTGRES_DB', 'myapp_development') %>
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default
database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
```

Any suggestions on how to get rid of this?

Comment: I got same situation but warning path was pointing  to `devise_auth_token`. That gem is using deprecated `connection_config` instead of `connection_db_config`. When I replaced manually deprecated line in gem file - warning went away. 

I searched in rspec for place where `connection_config` is used but I found nothing. Are you using any other gems ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jakubm. See my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I am also using `money-rails` but nothing was pointing to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After further debugging I was able to trace it to the `money-rails` gem.

https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/issues/601

Comment: I was seeing this in both money-rails AND honeybadger (v4.5), upgrading both has fixed it.
Morale of the story is to have a look at your rspec logs, they should highlight which line/gem is causing the issues.
Thanks Mark!

Comment: adding `ActiveRecord.legacy_connection_handling = false` in `application.rb` removed the warning.

Answer (score 1):

The root fix for me:

From
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config.to_h.deep_dup`

To
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection_db_config.configuration_hash.deep_dup`